# Unable to start appium through Jenkins programatically. This works when running from Eclipse

Tags: java, node.js, jenkins, npm, appium

Unable to start appium through Jenkins programatically. This works when running from Eclipse.

Jenkins giving following error on the console. This doesn't give any details error report.
I am using appium version 1.7.1 CLI npm. Getting following error:

```
===============================================
Demo App Automation Testing
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================
```

The script is working fine when I manually start appium from CLI and run BUILD NOW from Jenkins after commenting automatic appium start.

Do I miss any configuration settings? I have configured following items:

```
GIT_HOME :C:\Users\Hashili.MA\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151
MAVEN_HOME : C:\apache-maven-3.5.2
NODEJS_HOME : C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep verbose=10 in testng.xml in the parent tag and this should give you more details where the test is failing